# Как правильно: У подъезда или ПОД подъездом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, предлоги

Часто попадается на глаза словосочетание "под подъездом".
Например:
*Девочки, вот сижу, смотрю в окно, а **под подъездом** у меня клумба.*

Или:
*Правда, перед этим минут десять прогревала машину, неразумно брошенную вечером **под подъездом**.*

Звучит так же, как и "я за тобой скучаю".
Это новый городской диалект или допустимое для русского языка словосочетание?
Помогите определиться!

Answer (score 3):

В Нацкопусе есть подобные примеры:

*Даже теперь. Повеситься у вас под подъездом. ― Повесьтесь лучше под подъездом ВСНХ, ― на Варварской площади, ныне Ногина.* Ю. К. Олеша.

*Как узнала я, ― бросилась ждать под подъездом гимназии вас; как увидела, право, не знаю, что сделалось; не подошла: и ― за вами бежала*. Андрей Белый.

*Выезжаем в адрес. Видим, под подъездом желтый «мерсюк» стоит. Номер А-двести-двадцать-четыре-ЛУ, семьдесят восьмой регион. Елизавета Козырева.* Дамская охота (2001).

Это не новый городской диалект, а, скорее, устаревший, забытый, переставший быть общелитературным.

А откуда там предлог ПОД, каково его значение?
Можно предположить, что здесь он обозначает "расположение рядом с объектом", например: ***под*** Москвой, **под** вечер,  мужчина лет **под** сорок.

Comment: Выходит,  автор - любитель "анахронизмов". В его же произведении встретилось слово "мимовольно". Показалось - "коряво", оказалось у писателя Лескова это слово встречается в 5 разных произведениях.

Comment: Похоже, что анахронизм это только для литературного языка, а областных говорах встречается. В общем, стилистика выражения еще под вопросом. Вот, к примеру, современные вирши:Под подъездом жду тебя Снег пинаю, я, любя..Зимний вечер, холодно, но я терплю С розами в руках под подъездом тебя жду

Comment: Тут ещё с пониманием "подъезда" нужно разбираться. В Петербурге "подъездом" называют ведущий во двор проём для проезда транспорта (в нём или под ним повеситься сложно), а в Москве это то же, что парадная дверь многоквартирного дома.

Answer (score 0):

Такое употребление вполне корректно.

Одно из значений предлога "под" следующее: То же — при обозначении места, в непосредственную близость к к–рому что–н. направляется, ***или же — около к–рого, в непосредственной близости от к–рого что–н. происходит, находится***

Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Comment: Серж, а почему в думаете, что вполне корректно? Я вот это выражение впервые слышу, может быть, у него есть стилистическая пометка?

Comment: Вера, основываясь на значении предлога.

Comment: Ср.: под забором.

Comment: Я тоже никогда не слышал выражение "под подъездом".

Comment: Может быть, не все сочетания с предлогом ПОД могут иметь такое значение, например, под столом - это не рядом со столом.

Comment: И я такого не слышал, буквально для меня это означает "ниже уровня земли в месте подъезда".

Comment: См. в словарях: Ушакова, Кузнецова.

Comment: Серж, вот у Некрасова: "Размышления у парадного подъезда", грамотный был человек. А как посмотреть падежную форму в словарях, дайте ссылку на Ушакова, Кузнецова. А сами вы как говорите?

Comment: Я говорю у ''подъезда". Вера, в своем ответе я информацию взял из словаря Ушакова.

Comment: Ср.:Четыре человека отделились и во весь опор подскакали ***под самую крепость***. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

Comment: А еще есть выражение "под дверью". Ждать или стоять. Как и "под подъездом". Это просторечие, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Под подъездом к жилью клумб и неразумно брошенных машин нет и не предвидится. Подъезд сам есть уровень и имеет уровень соответствующий входу в здание. Всё, что ниже него (**под** из **под подъезда** об этом намекает), может быть только его частью или подземной частью строения. Вот **на подъезде, у подъезда, при подъезде** увидеть можно многое. Представление о **подъезде** как секции постройки — вещь в быту привычная, но не более того.